# Python OpenPMD notebook slider issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: Slider Issues]

I don't understand the issue here why slider does not show me the images however I can call specific images but this slider option not showing any images. Is there any one who can tell me what's going on with it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

I think this extension was missing from the installation however pip install command does not fixed the issue.